# How do I push my mysql database from phpmyadmin to heroku's cleardb?

Tags: mysql, heroku, phpmyadmin

I'm using WAMP server for running my php app. I have a database BOOK in phpmyadmin. How can I push this data to heroku. I have used add on to add cleardb to my app.

heroku config shows the database url too.

I tried

```
db:push mysql://root@localhost/BOOK
```

but it didn't work.

ERROR -->

```
 Failed to connect to database:
 Sequel::AdapterNotFound -> LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql
```

Comment: note that ClearDB is not a Heroku thing; it's a third party

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ClearDB recommends using `mysql` and `mysqldump` for importing data. From [Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.cleardb.com/developers/help/faq) on ClearDB.com:

```
For importing data into your MySQL database, we recommend that you use both the mysql command line client as well as the mysqldump database backup utility.
```

Syntax for importing is something like this:

```
$ mysql <dbname> -u <username> -p<password> < <file.sql>
```

Comment: where should i type this import command ? I'm using windows. I use mysql via wamp server

Comment: It needs to be tab from wherever the file is, on a system that has mysql command available

Comment: Exactly. That;s the question. Mysql command is unavailable. Is it still possible ?

Comment: I recently installed MYSQL workbench. Is it possible via that ?

Comment: @Abhishek Yes, you can do this via MYSQL workbench. Connect to your database, choose Data import -> Import form file.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have mysql installed locally, type "mysql" into terminal will inevitably result in "command not found". MAMP provides [command line syntax](http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/08/using-mysql-command-line-with-mamp.html) to resolve this problem. Thus, if we don't want to change $PATH to use 'mysql' command directly (there is really no need, in my opinion, if all we are going to use command line mysql for is database migration), we can run the following import syntax:

```
$/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot -u username -h hostname -p < exported_sql_file.sql
```

The CLI shall prompt for password input. And then the database in exported_sql_file.sql will be imported to clearDB. For how to acquire 'username', 'hostname', and 'password' for the import syntax, refer to [this tutorial for help](https://scotch.io/@phalconVee/deploying-a-php-and-mysql-web-app-with-heroku).

Comment: Hey man I saw you on the tutorial comments. I am also using MAMP to do this however I ran into a problem after running the line you described. After putting in my password, it says "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bafee8afa994bd'@'ip-10-0-120-40.ec2.internal' (using password: YES)" Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: I haven't touched that project for a long time, so I might not be of much help. But it seems to me that the password might be the issue. Try not putting the password in the command, but leave `-p` there. The CLI will prompt you to put in the password later. See if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I managed to make it work with mySQL Workbench.