# How to push my Mysql database to heroku via mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, heroku

I have created cleardb on heroku, I want to push my mysql database on local disk to heroku. I have mysql workbench installed. How can i push it to heroku ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I push my mysql database from phpmyadmin to heroku's cleardb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773926/how-do-i-push-my-mysql-database-from-phpmyadmin-to-herokus-cleardb)

Answer (score 1):

look at the output of `heroku config` - you will see an key called `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL` this is the connection string your application uses to talk to your database.

You can take this URL and break it up into it's constituent parts to get a username, password, host, port and database name which you can use in a connection via mysql workbench.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb for further reference.

Comment: Yes I know the CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL. Can you give more detailed insight into establishing connection via mysql workbench

Comment: I worked on phpmyadmin. I switched to mysql workbench for this purpose only

Answer (score 0):

If u want to just push your database, use console, it's simple:

```
heroku db:push
```

Comment: How can I get one console on my windows running? I have always worked with phpmyadmin in wamp server

Comment: E.g if you use TotalCommander then navigate to the root directory of your app. Type cmd and press enter. You will get a console.
Maybe you have to install heroku toolbelt.
https://toolbelt.heroku.com/

Comment: This feature has been deprecated - https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/3/18/push_and_pull_databases_to_and_from_heroku.